# Alignment issue with bootstrap div on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing web application which is mobile responsive, i have slider on home page and select city dropdown on slider image. every thing woring fine with desktop, when open the application on MOTO E (540*960 resolution). i can see the image but dropdown is not visible. how can i resolve my issue.

below is my html  bootstrap code

```
 <div class="carousel-inner ">
        <div class="item active">
            <img class="img-responsive slideropacity" src="~/Images/Home/Slider/slider01.jpg" alt="slider">
            <div class="slider-content">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div class="btn-group" id="btncity">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default drp-btn">select your city</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle drp-btn-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu city-dropdown-menu" id="city-dropdown-menu"></ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Thanks in advance for help..

Comment: In `bootstrap` class `carousel-inner` always has `overflow: hidden` may be that's why your dropdown is not visible, try using `overflow: visible;`.

Comment: Can you share a JS fiddle... difficult to understand...

Comment: i removed <div class="carousel-inner">. still im not getting